# Is it possible to access a webpage without a webbrowser?

Tags: c#

I want to visit a web page (it has to be accessed, nothing needs to be read, modified, etc. Just accessed). I don't want to use webbrowser.

Comment: @Jayram that has nothing to do with C#.

Comment: Where did u mentioned about C# in your question?

Comment: "Is it possible to access a webpage without a webbrowser?" I guess it depends on your definition of "webbrowser".  If it means "any program that accesses a webpage", then by definition the answer is "no".

Comment: @mbeckish I mean a Webbrowser control.

Comment: I see.  You should accept @Sampriti Panda's answer then.

Answer (score 6):

Just do a cURL GET request.

```
curl http://example.com/
```

And if you want to use C#, then

```
using System.Net;

string url = "https://www.example.com/";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use Fiddler to send request to the remote server (it is very helpful for service debuging).

Answer (score 0):

try to use [`WebClient` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

for example:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
string reply = client.DownloadString (address);
```